# QPSK implementation with 2 BPSK

Tags: qpsk, bpsk

I have a tiny problem with understanding a thing here.

for the 1st the phase shift is 0 degrees, so on its modulated wave we put 180-degree phase shift.

for the 2nd  0, the oscillator puts a 90-degree phase shift in the carrier signal and as it's a 0-degree we have to put 180-degree shift.

When we sum up the two 0's in the final wave, how are we getting the -135 degree???

I'm unable to understand the summing. https://prnt.sc/gP0OypJ3n_jB
[image]

Comment: also, removed the numerous unrelated tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constellation points are the sum of {+1, -1} and {+1j, -1j}, so you get the points {+1+1j, +1-1j, -1+1j, -1-1j}, which have these odd multiples of 45° as angles.

That's one way to look at it.

The other is to realize that if you had only multiples of 90° as angles, only the inphase- or quadrature component *can* be active at a time, as the amplitude of the other must be 0. But in your schematic, you see that both are active with a non-zero amplitude at the same time.

In the end, it *really doesn't matter*. The receiver gets the signal with a different, arbitrary phase, anyways, and will rotate it however it sees fit for best decidability. So, maybe it is assumed that the 90° point on transmit side gets simply rotated to be 135° by the receiver (just as any other points are rotated by the same amount).

Comment: Hello Sir, https://prnt.sc/HrQ6niQhkfYC please see... 
I'm able to understand how 180 +270  phase shift results in -135

Comment: sum of the two phases (180+270)/2 = 225

Comment: Have you read the first paragraph of my answer?

Comment: 225 - 360 = -135

Comment: Thank you Sir @Marcus

Comment: @DanBoschen ouch, you're right

Comment: @Jency my apologies! My answer was wrong. I'll need to correct it.

Comment: @DanBoschen finally gotten around to fixing this. That was much too late, sorry, Jency.